# How to use SeekToLast to get last key value

Tags: go, leveldb

I want the best performance code to get the last key value in the database. I google this problem and find SeekToLast function but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: pls explain what is not understood. package should be installed as written here - https://github.com/DataDog/leveldb

Comment: I want a code example ... something that is simple to understand

Comment: thank you for the link I think my problem is that I am using this package github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb instead of your link

Comment: use another package:) here you can find an example - https://github.com/jmhodges/levigo/blob/master/leveldb_test.go#L109

Comment: this sounds helpful thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean [goleveldb](https://github.com/syndtr/goleveldb)?

If so then it will look like

```
iter := db.NewIterator(nil, nil)
ok := iter.Last()
if ok {
    key = iter.Key()
    value = iter.Value()
}
iter.Release() // Note: you should first get data and then release iterator
err = iter.Error()
```

Or to iterate from the end to the beginning.

```
iter := db.NewIterator(nil, nil)
for ok := iter.Last(); ok; ok = iter.Prev() {
    // Use key/value.
    // ...
}
iter.Release()
err = iter.Error()
```

You may also retrieve last key-value with specific prefix, or in general from some range (more details: https://godoc.org/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb#DB.NewIterator)

```
iter := db.NewIterator(util.BytesPrefix([]byte("prefix_")), nil)
// or
iter := db.NewIterator(util.Range{
    Start: []byte("prefix_03"),
    Limit: []byte("prefix_04"),
}), nil)
```

Does it help?